# Flutter open popup menu above list item

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I am making a chat app in Flutter with Firestore but I am stumped with one of the requirement: Making a reaction menu appear above a chat dialog. I need that when the user long press on a chat text the reaction menu would appear above the current chat position. Something like Facebook Messenger app:

[image]

I have look around and found https://medium.com/@duytq94/facebook-reactions-with-flutter-9019ce8b95b8 but it seems it is too much for just a simple function (making a popup menu appear above a list tile and don't need the animation). I also found this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reaction_button, but it does not allow to wrap the widget around another to open up the reacton menu. Is there a simple way that I can archive this? I have looked into PopupMenuButton but it only allows onPressed and not long press.

Comment: i think on this layout its best to used overlay widget : ```https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html````

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Overlay` widget. I make a simple example for you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Temp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TempState createState() => _TempState();
}

class _TempState extends State<Temp> {
  GlobalKey floatingKey = LabeledGlobalKey("Floating");
  bool isFloatingOpen = false;
  OverlayEntry floating;

  OverlayEntry createFloating() {
    RenderBox renderBox = floatingKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          left: offset.dx,
          width: renderBox.size.width,
          top: offset.dy - 50,
          child: Material(
            elevation: 20,
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("I'm floating overlay")
            )
          )
        );
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          key: floatingKey,
          color: Colors.red,
          onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              if(isFloatingOpen) floating.remove();
              else {
                floating = createFloating();
                Overlay.of(context).insert(floating);
              }
              isFloatingOpen = !isFloatingOpen;
            });
          },
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried out your example and it is very like what I am looking for. One question is that is there a way to close the overlay when press outside, and not just when click on the button?

Comment: Also how would this work for a ListView? The ````isFloatingOpen```` is just one variable to manage the open and close status of the Overlay

Comment: You can wrap the whole scaffold with GestureDetector and use the onTap to close the overlay if it's open. And yes it could work with a ListView, I have tried it before. Btw, can use upvote my answer if it's useful? Sorry but I'm trying to collect reputation haha

Comment: So how do I assign the floating key for each ListItem? Supposed I have a list of 100 item from a data source and use ListView.builder to build it into ListView, do I have to create 100 different ````floatingKey```` to assign to each ListItem?

Comment: You can make model class for the data so every data will have its own key.

Comment: Can you demonstrate it in your answer for better understanding? I still cannot picture it clearly